# Switching context in SSIS data sources

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

The requirement:
I have an SSIS project that will run on data in SQL Server, possibly logging in to the SQL Server using integrated authentication.
That project includes one section that allows end users to add a select query as a source for one dataflow. (The product allows the user to add data categorization and filtering type rules in configuration files).
I want those queries supplied by the user to be run in a restricted context with read-only access. It must not be possible for someone to trash the database by adding a `DELETE`or `DROP`to their query.

First pass solution:
Create a read-only user on the database and use `EXECUTE AS ... WITH NO REVERT`to restrict the context of the query to the read-only user. Unfortunately this does not fully work. SSIS uses prepared statements in the data source components, and `WITH NO REVERT` is not permitted by SQL Server in prepared statements.

Questions:
Is there a way to force SSIS to use ad-hoc queries in place of prepared statements in the OLEDB data source component?
or ... Is there another way to force SSIS to change execution context for a data source component?

I have one other solution up my sleeve: Use a script component source. The script component can set the user context in any number of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I settled on for this is to have a script source component that wraps the user-supplied `SELECT` with `EXECUTE AS user WITH NO REVERT`. I'm convinced that using the permissions structure to prevent unwnated action is the better than using transactions.

I created two connection managers. One (called connection_RO) is an ADO.NET connection manager that is only ever used by the component that executes the user-supplied queries. The other (connection_RW) is used for everything else, including transforming the data from the user-supplied queries and writing it back.

There is one script source component that executes the user-supplied query. It prefixes the query with the EXECUTE AS ... clause to lock the user into the read-only context.

The next problem to solve was that all connections are pooled by default, and when you pick up a connection that was used previously in a pool the framework sends a `sp_reset_connection`. That throws an exception because SQL Server sees it as an attempt to escalate privilege. Therefore the connection_RO connection manager had to be configured with no pooling.

The final result is that I can run the user-supplied queries with confidence that the user can do no damage, either maliciously or by accident.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers on stackoverflow suggesting wrapping it in a BEGIN TRAN / ROLLBACK TRAN. This could be in separate SQL Tasks, removing the ability to disable them with sneaky injection. But they could still inject DROP DATABASE into your data flow. No way to roll back that one.

Have you checked whether DML even runs in the source of a dataflow?

I do question the architecture of this though..... running user defined queries in SSIS?

Comment: Thank you for that. I have checked that `INSERT`and `DELETE` work in context. I have not tested much else, but that is enough to be concerned about. Using a transaction is not an option I had considered and it is worth testing, so thanks for that. I have implemented a test using a script component source and that seems to work as required, so I'll probably just go with that.  As to running user-supplied queries in SSIS: there is an unavoidable requirement to run user-supplied queries and all the other data manipulation is in SSIS ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ad-hoc` queries in `OLEDB source` by using `SQL Command from Variable` option .You can create a variable and type in your sql query and use it in the OLEDB source component .Use XML Configuration and add the variable to it.So if you change the `query` in XML that will be reflected in SSIS during `runtime` . However SSIS is heavily dependent on `Metadata`.Even before execution , SSIS validates the metadata .If you change the query in XML  (such as changing the column name) ,then SSIS will discover metadata mismatch and the package will `fail`

Comment: I'm already using SQL Command from Variable option to get the user-supplied query into the data source. The problem is that SSIS is automatically wrapping that in sp_prepare, and in that context SQL Server will not accept the `WITH NO REVERT`. As long as I cannot use `WITH NO REVERT` an intelligent user could break out of the read-only context just by putting `REVERT` in their query. The problem I need to solve is to force the user to stay in the read-only context. That might be by stopping SSIS from using `sp_prepare` (ie; using an ad-hoc, not prepared, statement).